# iOS 7 Keyboard Predictions

Tags: ios, internationalization, keyboard, uikeyboard, chinese-locale

We are adding support to our iOS 7 app to allow for Asian users.  However, for keyboards using Chinese characters, there is a scroll view containing predictive text at the top of if.  Once the user begins to type, a horizontal scroll view appears just above the keyboard, and is never dismissed.

Is there a way to detect when the user has an iOS 7 Chinese lettering keyboard with predictions turned on?  This way we can move elements up a little higher to compensate for it.

Comment: just wondering, but shouldn't auto-layout take care of that? it might be part of this 'under bottom bars' behavior, you have with tabbars too.

Comment: Does not appear to be helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!  First listen for UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changed:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

The notification will send a dictionary over containing a number of keyboard parameters.  The height of UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey will give you a real time update of the keyboard height, including predictions from Asian keyboards.

```
- (void)changed:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue *keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
    float keyboardHeight = keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height;
}
```

Comment: Hats off to the answer

Answer (score 2):

//ViewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardFrameDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardFrameWillChange:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)keyboardFrameDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];
    CGRect inputPanelFrame = self.inputPanel.frame;

     UIView *superView = [ self.inputPanel superview];

    inputPanelFrame.origin.y = (superView.frame.size.height -(keyboardFrame.size.height+self.inputPanel.frame.size.height));

    self.inputPanel.frame = inputPanelFrame;
}


- (void)keyboardFrameWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];
    CGRect inputPanelFrame = self.inputPanel.frame;
      UIView *superView = [ self.inputPanel superview];
    inputPanelFrame.origin.y = (superView.frame.size.height -(keyboardFrame.size.height+self.inputPanel.frame.size.height));

    self.inputPanel.frame = inputPanelFrame;

}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so that the code is formatted properly? (Use the preview feature at the page bottom.) Thank you!